# why is the second last line showing a subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba

the task is to consolidate data from different files into one file.The range to be selected is a column vector of 4 cells.the output is required in array(n*4 distribution)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1


Sub RalphieReactor()
Dim filenames() As Variant, i As Integer, A() As Variant, j As Integer, nw As Integer
Dim twb As Workbook, awb As Workbook, userrange As Range, importrange As String
Set twb = ThisWorkbook
filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)
nw = UBound(filenames)
For i = 1 To nw
    Workbooks.Open filenames(i)
    Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set userrange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range", Type:=8)
    importrange = userrange.Address
    For j = 1 To 4
    A(i, j) = awb.Sheets(1).Range(importrange).Cells(i, j)
   Next j


Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you size `A`? (`ReDim`)?

Comment: I'd also avoid the syntax `Workbooks.Open filenames(i)` and refer to it using `ActiveWorkbook`. You can simply `Set` a new workbook variable when opening and close it later down the line.

Comment: Was confused how to define the size but it just clicked now.thanks for that but the time format in like 00:00 is not copying as it is.how should I deal with that

Comment: Could you elaborate @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `A() As Variant` has the meaning of *A will be an array of type Variant - but the exact size is not fixed yet*. In your case, you cannot declare the size because it is depending on the number of selected files, so that's okay.

However, before you can use this array, you have to specify it's size (because the VBA runtime needs to reserve some memory space and to do so, it needs to know the size to calculate how much memory is needed). If you don't, the array contains no members at all and you get the *Subscript out of Range*-error. Fortunately, you get this error, meaning that the VBA runtime prevents that something is written into memory that was not reserved, causing horrible things (called "Stack Overflow" or "Heap Overflow").

In VBA, the command to assign memory to an error at runtime is `Redim`. You need a 2-dimensional array, the first dimension is `nw` (number of selected files), the second is 4, so the statement is

```
Redim A(1 to nw, 1 to 4)
```

(you could write `Redim A(nw, 4)` for short, but I think it's better to specify lower and upper bounds).
Put that statement right before you open the outer `For`-loop.

Comment: Used the format("hh:mm") commmand for time copying problem.Thank you everybody for their support

Comment: In your question, you are talking about an *Index out of Range*-Error. If you have an additional problem, eg. with time formatting, ask a new question. SO is about asking a specific question and collect answers. Good answers should be upvoted and, if it helped the user who asked the question (=you), be accepted. Later, if someone searches SO for something similar (eg by searching for *Index out of Range* in VBA), they should find an answer that fits to him without asking again. At least that's the theory...